# Using a QueryStringParameter and ControlParameter in a GridView ItemTemplate in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET application. This application has a GridView. This GridView has a TemplateField that needs to include hyperlinks. I want those hyperlinks to navigate to a hyperlink in the form of

```
add.aspx?id1=[QueryStringParameterValue]&id2=[ControlParameterValue]&id3=[CurrentRecordID]
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, what is the best way to redirect the user to another page and take into consideration:

- A value from the current query string (the QueryStringParameterValue)
- The value of a selected item in a drop down list (the ControlParameterValue)
- The current record ID

Currently, my GridView looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDownList" Runat="Server" DataSourceID="myDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" />
<GridView ID="myGridView" runat="Server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#">View Details</a>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But now I'm stuck. How do I wire-up the three items I want to include within my ItemTemplate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPX

```
<a href='<%# CreateUrl(Eval("id")) %>'>View details </a>
```

C#

```
public string CreateUrl(obj value)
{
       var p = request.querystring["querystringname"];
       if(p!=null)
       {
         return "add.aspx?id1=" + p + "&id2=" + mydropdownlist.selectedvalue + "&id3=" + id;
       }
        return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the request data from the response data. this way if something changes (replace the dropdown list or querystring with a form post, etc) the gridview won't change.

code behind

```
protected string Value1{get {return Request.QueryString["key"];}}
protected string Value2 {get {return DropDown.SelectedValue;}}
```

markup

```
<GridView ID="myGridView" runat="Server">
  <Columns>
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%=string.Format("add.aspx?id1={0}&id2={1}&id3={2}", Value1, Value2, Eval("ID"))%>'>View Details</a>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```